# too many re renders on custom hook when there is no infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've created a custom hook within my **React** app to integrate with a global `Audio` object singleton. I'm using **Redux** to dispatch the new tracks slug when the audio source has been updated, and then subsequently checking if the dispatched slug is the same as the one attached to the hook (to check if the track is mounted).

However I've come across an issue where my code seems to reduce into an infinite loop, and I cannot figure out why. Here's my hook code:

```
import * as Player from "playerSlice.js";
const usePlayer = (slug) => {
    const __USE_PLAYER_SLUG = slug.trim();

    // Redux setup
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const playerState = useSelector(state => state.player);

    // State setup
    const [state, setState] = useReducer((state, newState) => ({...state, ...newState}), {
        mounted: false,
        playing: false
    });

    // All of these functions will first check to make sure that the slug
    // that has been passed to usePlayer is set in the redux state (mounted)
    const toggle = () => ensureMounted(() => {
        if(!state.playing){
            play();
        } else {
            pause();
        }
    });
    const play = () => ensureMounted(() => {
        __GLOBAL_AUDIO.play();
        // According to React my error is here
        setState({ playing: true });
    }); 
    const pause = () => ensureMounted(() => {
        __GLOBAL_AUDIO.pause();
        setState({ playing: false });
    }); 

    const mount = callback => {
        __GLOBAL_AUDIO.src = cdn(`/track/audio/${__USE_PLAYER_SLUG}.mp3`);
        onLoad(() => {
            callback();
            // React also says the problem arises from here
            dispatch(Player.mount(__USE_PLAYER_SLUG));
        });
    };
    const ensureMounted = callback => {
        if(state.mounted){
            callback();
        } else {
            mount(callback);
        }
    };

    const onLoad = callback => {
        const ready = () => {
            callback();
            __GLOBAL_AUDIO.removeEventListener("loadedmetadata", ready);
        };
        __GLOBAL_AUDIO.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", ready);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const isMounted = __USE_PLAYER_SLUG === playerState.currentSlug;
        setState({ mounted: isMounted });
    }, [playerState.currentSlug]);

    return {
        playing: state.playing,
        toggle: toggle,
        play: play,
        pause: pause,
    };
};
```

And here is my `playerSlice` code:

```
export const playerSlice = createSlice({
    name: "player",
    initialState: { 
        currentSlug: null,
    },
    reducers: {
        mount: (state, { payload: slug }) => {
            state.currentSlug = slug;
        }
    }
});

export const { mount } = playerSlice.actions;
export default playerSlice.reducer;
```

As you can see, the `setState` within the `useEffect` is *only* called when a new **Redux** value is dispatched, and the `dispatch` *only* takes place when a new audio source is mounted - which should only be once.

I'm not sure why this is happening, however I'm very new to **Redux** so maybe there's some logic that I'm missing?

All help is appreciated,
Cheers.

Comment: Remove the else and mount part from ensureMounted
And see if it helps, I believe your reducer is not working, check https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer and scroll down

Comment: @iunfixit why would removing the else and mount fix it? hhaa